# Which database engine is most suitable to handle array values?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, elasticsearch, sphinx

The often seen use case is when one store a list of tag to an item
tag: [123,233,...], and the result should be query-able like "getting all rows with tag 233".

Seems like the most advocated approach in mysql is having another table and do join. However given so many other database/search engines available now, e.g. elasticsearchh, mongodb,  postgresql, I would like to know if any of these new databases had built-in support for this structure. I am not talking about simply the ability to get the job done, but the database architecture that is optimized for this kind of query.

Comment: What, precisely, is insufficient about using a relational database for this?

Comment: Actually it is not the inefficiency of relational database, but I am recently rebuilding my project structure so I want to consider other technologies that might have specially catered for this. (plus not a fan of join)

Comment: I said "insufficient," not "inefficient." You haven't yet said _why_ you think using a relational database is less than ideal for you. How can we possibly propose a solution to your perceived problem when you haven't stated what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has built-in support for [array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/arrays.html) data types including array operations and indexes. Also if you need – it's possible to store more complex data, even json objects.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's no silver bullet, I don't think there's something most suitable to do something.
And if you ask for some personal choice, I prefer [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/).